# Inter-process communication with external command from installshield

Tags: ipc, installshield

I need to execute a external command from installshield and want to display the progress inside installshield. I can modify the external command to send the data in any possible way - but so far the only solution I found was writing the progress-information to a file and read it in install shield: However this seems to me like a bad way to do this, as I want to prevent unnecessary write access to the hard disk.

Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Is your problem just the communication of the progress (i.e. you've already solved how to display it once you know it)? What are you using to launch the process -- C++, InstallScript, or something else?

Comment: @MichaelUrman Yes, displaying the progress is not a problem once I have the information. To launch the process use InstallScript `LaunchAppAndWait` currently, but if a solution involves a different way to start the process, I'm happy with it as long as I can retrieve informations from my process in InstallShield.